# C# C継承先のフォームでコントロールがズレる

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

お世話になります。

フォームの基本クラスでボタンなどをフォームの右下に張り付け、Anchorを
Bottom,Rightにし、それを継承したフォームでClientSizeを操作すれば、
その大きさに合わせて張り付けたボタンなども右下に配置されると思っていたのですが、
実際は継承したフォームでは、開始位置が継承先と同じ座標に現れ、
サイズを変更すると、ズレた位置からAnchorの設定どおりに動いてしまいます。

そのため、今まではいつも継承した後はデザイン画面からズルズルと
手動で右下に移動させているのですが、さすがに嫌になりました。

考えてみれば、確かにこの動きは当たり前かもしれませんが、希望としては
継承先でも、継承元でAnchorにBottom,Rightになっているようなら、
開始直後でも配置先を右下からの相対位置にしたいものです。

これらのことは、既存のプロパティか何かでできるものでしょうか。
もしくは、他に何か方法があるのでしょうか。

打開策があるようでしたらお教えください。

よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

継承元フォームの内容をフォームではなくユーザーコントロールとして実装してみてはいかがでしょうか。

1. 新規にユーザーコントロール作成しForm1が持っているUIと機能を移植
2. Form2（継承先フォーム）をForm1ではなくSystem.Windows.Forms.Formを継承する形に戻す
3. Form2のデザイナで作成したユーザーコントロールを配置し、Dock=Fillとする。
4. Form1は不要となるので削除する

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございました！
お教えいただいた方法で、うまくいきました！
考えてみれば、確かにその通りでした^^;
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

(コメントで指摘があったので追記しました)
以下の内容は、**継承元フォームのボタンに派生クラスがアクセスできる**前提です

継承元をどうやって指定（変更）してるのかわかりませんが
VS2015のテンプレートだと、継承されたフォーム というのがあります。これで継承元を指定しても、フォームのサイズは継承元のままのようですのでボタン位置はずれませんね

通常のフォームとして追加して、継承元を変えた場合
フォームのサイズを指定してなければ、継承元を変えた段階でフォームのサイズも継承元のサイズになりましたので、これもボタン位置がずれるということはなさそうですが

ただし、一度でもサイズ変更してから継承元を変えると、その段階でフォームのサイズが上書きされるがボタン位置はそのままなので、位置がずれますね

テンプレートに継承されたフォームが無いようであれば、フォームを追加した後真っ先に継承元を変えてからサイズ変更するようにすればよいのではないでしょうか
（VS2015で確認したので他のバージョンだとまた違う動作かもしれませんが）

Comment: この現象は派生クラスの`InitializeComponent()`内でコントロールのサイズを変更する場合、`SuspendLayout()`がコールされているので`Anchor`等のレイアウト変更に基づく機能が動作しないことが原因です。なので継承フォームであってもサイズ変更後にファイルを閉じて再表示すると発生します。

Comment: すくなくとも2015のCommunityで確認する限り、フォームデザイナーが派生されたクラスでInitializeComponentを生成する際に、ボタンの位置も再設定するコードを出力します
サイズ変更後にファイルを閉じて再表示しても、最後に表示された位置にボタンは表示されているようです
この位置はアンカーを考慮して算出された値ですので、ずれるということはないようですが（デザイナ画面上、フォームサイズの変更に合わせて位置が変更されるのが確認できる）

Comment: 「ボタンの位置‌​も再設定するコード」を出力するためには、当然派生クラス側からボタンにアクセスできる必要があります。ですがC#フォームデザイナーの既定のアクセス修飾子(`Modifiers`)は`private`ですので、明示的に変更しない限りそのような動作にはなりません。既定値が`Friend`のVBと勘違いしていないでしょうか。

Comment: 確認しましたが、確かに継承元フォームでボタンのModifiersをprotectedに変更したものを使ってました。
であれば、解決策として継承元フォームのボタンをprotectedにする方法もありですね。
ただ、privateなボタンは継承したフォームのデザイナで位置変更すら不可能なようですが、質問の内容をみると変更できてるように見えますが